# Deseasonalizing time series in Julia? (monthly temperature)

Tags: time-series, julia

Is there a function to deseasonalize time series in Julia? In this case monthly temperatures.
So I need to deseasonalize and detrend a temperature time serien and calculate the anomalies at the end.

I searched for it and found nothing.

Comment: This might be useful: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/package-for-deseasonalizing/9275

Answer (score 0):

Try:

https://github.com/viraltux/Smoothers.jl/
or
https://github.com/LAMPSPUC/StateSpaceModels.jl/
or
https://github.com/baggepinnen/SingularSpectrumAnalysis.jl/

I prefer stl from the first link because of its simplicity.